# Specializing template member function to handle both std::string and char[] arguments

Tags: c++, templates

I have a template member function of a class that I'm using for adding various different types to a list, with special handling and wrapping (everything ends up wrapped in a var object) for specific types:

```
template<typename V> const var& addvar(const V& v);

template<> const var& addvar<std::string>(const std::string& v) {/*stuff*/}
```

However, I'm passing around strings (well, const char arrays) like this to it:

```
object.addvar("lol");
```

Although I'm handling everything as std::strings, this pops in as some sort of const char array reference in the template parameter type deduction.  So I get an error about not having a function for it, even with the above std::string specialization.  I'm familiar with template array size deduction, so I'm trying to use that format to create an addvar that can handle such a thing, something like:

```
template<size_t N> const var& addvar<char>(const char& (&v)[N]) {/*stuff*/}
```

But things are going horribly with compiler errors about illegal arrays of references.  This is in VC++ 2010, if there's any specific weirdness with that, but I get the feeling I'm messing up something fundamental here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't partially specialize template function, so it has to be an overload (= a template that doesn't share anything with the initial `addvar` template function):

```
template<size_t N> const var& addvar(const char (&v)[N]) {/*stuff*/}
```

Comment: Ah ha, I tried that with addvar<char> and it didn't work, but doing it your way with no <char> works fine.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
template<size_t N> const var& addvar<char>(const char& (&v)[N]) {/*stuff*/}
                                                     ^
```

Delete `&` after `const char`, you are trying to specialize for array of references that way, which is not what you want (and is illegal either way).

Comment: This gives me the error "illegal use of explicit template arguments"

Answer (score 1):

The function would look like this:

```
template <std::size_t N>
void foo(const char (&a)[N])
```

But your problem is that you cannot partially specialize a function. What however you can do, is defining a simple overload, which will be preferred and called from the compiler.